# FLAC file containing time series

Tags: python, time-series, flac

I need the content of a FLAC file containing time-series (it's not an audio file). I tried to open it with the soundfile library:

```
import soundfile as sf

data, samplerate = sf.read('input/data.flac')
print(data)
```

But it results in an error "Format not recognised".

Does anybody have an idea, what format the following file could be and how to solve this problem?

[image: Start of file]

I'm not able to post the binary data, but the hex code:

```
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
```

Comment: A flac file should start with `fLaC` (note mixed case) which is hex `664C6143` which is in your file, but not at the start. There seems to be some extra data at the start of the file causing the problem.